# Use tensorflow for variable shape inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am currently trying to use a tensorflow model/function to do calculations with variable length inputs. 
More precisely, I have two list as inputs (let's call them `L_1` and `L_2`), each of which contains the same number of arrays, but each of these arrays has a different shape. I need to apply the tensorflow function to the individual tuples (`L_1[0], L_2[0]), (L_1[1], L_2[1]), ..., (L_1[n], L_2[n]`), if possible in vectorized fashion.

This is the function, which takes two tensors as input and returns the (variable length) result:

```
def nearest_point_calculations(input):
    surface_points = tf.expand_dims(input[0], axis=0)
    border_centers = tf.expand_dims(input[1], axis=1)
    dif = tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(tf.subtract(surface_points, border_centers), axis=-1)
    min = tf.argmin(dif, axis=1)
    return tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(tf.squeeze(tf.gather(surface_points, min, axis=1), axis=0))
```

The function works fine on individual inputs, but I want to process the whole list of arrays at once, so I do not just want to use a while-loop to process everything sequentially.

The only working method I was able to create was the following:

```
def nearest_point_wrapper(surface_points, border_centers):
    return tf.map_fn(nearest_point_calculations, (surface_points, border_centers), fn_output_signature=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=(None, 2)))

def calculate_nearest_point_init(surface_points, border_centers):
    surface_points_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(surface_points, dtype=tf.float32)
    border_centers_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(border_centers, dtype=tf.float32)
    return nearest_point_wrapper(surface_points_tensor, border_centers_tensor)
```

So this method creates two `RaggedTensors` for the two inputs and uses `map_fn` on the two `RaggedTensors`. But, creating `RaggedTensors` is extremely slow if done on the fly (it takes about 1.5 seconds while creating a single tensor for each sub-array only needs 0.17 seconds in total).

So in the second example, I tried to convert each array into a tensor individually (which is much faster) and to use `map_fn` on the resulting list of inputs:

```
def nearest_point_wrapper(surface_points, border_centers):
    return tf.map_fn(nearest_point_calculations, (surface_points, border_centers), fn_output_signature=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=(None, 2)))

def calculate_nearest_point_init(surface_points, border_centers):
    surface_points_tensor = [tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32) for x in surface_points]
    border_centers_tensor = [tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32) for x in border_centers]
    return nearest_point_wrapper(surface_points_tensor, border_centers_tensor)
```

But with this method, I just get a `ValueError` telling me that
**the shapes of the tensors within the first list do not match**.

I wonder why `map_fn` does even care about that, since it is just supposed to take the first entry of the first list and the first entry of the second list and apply to function to them? 
Why does it even check whether the individual elements in the list have the same shape?

Comment: What device do you wanna execute your function, GPU or CPU?

Comment: On the GPU, for CPU I would just program everything with numpy but a fast GPU implementation is what I would prefer.